# Where should I start to make my own sonograph writer?

Tags: open-source, software-development, c++, audio

I've been having recurring daydreams about how freeing it would be to have my own spectrogram/sonograph program, one where silence was an RGB value of [0,0,0], and where the loudest volume was [255,255,255], and where the closest thing to silence was [1,0,0] ...ect, in an ordered list with every color as a volume level, and with sounds stored as bitmaps. 
But I'm a newb who has only ever done stuff with pictures and console apps... ...I don't even know WHERE to begin to start this particular undertaking off on a good note.

Do you know of any good gpl resources or source code to help me start this project?

I just need a starting place, I know that whole books could and probably HAVE covered this topic in-depth, but if someone could maybe give me a list of those books [or alternatively software or web tutorials which fill the same role], those would be suitable answers. I just need to know how to start 
(I already know how to code bitmaps in a hex editor and kinda know how to read and write files in C++, so... I just need help with this archaic-knowledge-feeling sound generation info)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome aboard. I am afraid that this question might be seen as is of-topic, as it is very broad. You might just want to ask for a library here, although personally I would not bother & would just code it all myself.

Readers, please note that this is ***not*** intended as an answer. It is just a comment that grew, and grew, and …

If I understand correctly, you want to detect sounds and display them as colo(u)rs ? I am not sure what you mean by “with sounds stored as bitmaps”, unless you want to display an image for each sound. Maybe you could/should display in a different way, like a chart, where you can see historical data, not just the current sound? Maybe, in v2.0, you could have a way to export the sounds detected (volume, duration, etc)? You could also add “Reporting” of most frequent values/average values; if you are measuring something like street noise, you could compare today with yesterday, the same day last week/last year, this month with the same month last year, etc, etc.

If you just want to display, then you don’t need to know “know how to read and write files in C++”.

First, of course, you need some hardware to detect the sound.  Are you planning to use a PC, or do you want to also learn a new platform such as Raspberry Pi (I prefer the [Onion Omega 2](https://onion.io/omega2/), but YMMV).

Next, how often do you want to sample the sound? Once per day/hours/minute/second? Or “as often as possible”?

If you struggle with C++, maybe consider another language? Python is much simpler, very popular & well supported, and has many, many, many, plug-in libraries, which make it very powerful.

Is your pseudo cod really as simple as this?

```
forever (or until interrupted)
    measure sound
    update display
    delay (if you want to wait between samples)
```

It’s probably best to choose a language which has good graphic capabilities. For C++ that probably means learning a library like Qt. For Python, our resident guru @SteveBarnes can help you :-)

You might want to consider  how to “grow” this application, learning new things along the way. For instance, you could start it as a PC based app. Then you could have it not display anything, but instead send some info to a web server, which updates a page that you can visit in your browser. Or you could make it an Android App, add raspberry Pi somehow, etc … If any of this sounds like learning fun, then stop now and make a plan –don’t just jump straight in. You don’t want to find yourself halfway up the mountain only to look across and realize that you are on the wrong mountain ;-)

This sounds like a very simple project, but it could grow and grow (see my V2..0 above), adding features and helping you learn new skills as you go.

Sister sites to be aware of:

- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/
- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Tools you need:

- An IDE such as MS Visual Studio or Visual Code for C++ (or Eclipse CDT, Netbeans, etc) or PyCharm for Python
- Learn to use the debugger, it is your absolute best friend when developing software
- Maybe look into Static ode Analysis (AKA Linting) to try to make your code even more bug free
- Learn Unit Testing and end to end testing in V2, if you network your app

And so much more. I could go on & on, but this “comment” is long enough already ;-)

Good luck – and I am sure that you will have great fun with your dream

Comment: I want to be able to draw sounds.  The X coordinate = time. Y coordinate equal pitch. Color equal amplitude. Then I can process images into music and vice-versa and also get to create all kinds of unique timbres

Comment: Audacity has a spectrogram, but it's read only (unless there is a secret way to get it working). Adobe has a read-write spectrogram but it costs money so I gotta write my own read-write

Comment: Also thank you for your response, I like your positivity and knowledgeability, I was hoping for more info on good resources for generating tones in C++, so that I could create something like a drawing app, and then use SDL or something to analyze each pixel's value and then decrypt it into a sine wave; and again, like, that's ALOT of stuff, but my problem is that I don't know where to start learning about tone generation

Comment: Lots of good questions, I was thinking about leaving many of those attributes to be user defined by the metadata of the bitmap actually, thanks for asking, and if bitmaps can't store that metadata: I was gonna pack em in with an XML document. Most people might use the human hearing range, but some people might want to make music for bats. Furthermore: the scale is determined by the space between the bounds, to allow for smooth apegios, and more flexibility and whatnot, also sinewaves are standar but other primitives should be allowed instead or as well like tris or squares

Comment: Aha! So, you don't just want to listen to sounds with a microphone? You want to generate them and then measure them? That's certainly good for testing. Your main problem is that this question will probably be closed as off-topic since it is too broad. You should probably ask it piece by piece on various sites. please update your question with as much info as you can give. If you want to ask for a tone generation application or software library, that is on-topic. You could also ask for a tone generation device at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, I'm autistic AND ADHD so that may be hindering our communication somewhat. How best should I ask? I want gpl C++ libraries that let me generate tones, and/or a good link to a good tutorial, I mean that is VERY specific, but those are only CLOSE to being software... ...they're very fringe and I  don't know where to ask but here

Comment: Well, you have a very bug question, asking lots & lots of little questions.  If it gets put on hold as too broad, just edit it to ask something like "I am looking for a C++ library which will let me generate tones from my code". Unfortunately, links to books or tutorials have been off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites for years now :-( Also, I think I misunderstood your question - do you want do play  a sound and display a bitmap associated with it? Or to detect a sound and display a bitmap associated with it?

Comment: Detect a bitmap and play a sound associated with it (scan the pixels per column load them into a buffer and use nyquist shannon types of simultaneity to get things that sound like instruments to happen from polysynth mixing)

Comment: So if when a picture goes in: a song comes out. Each vertical pixel line in the image is an instant of sound

Comment: That is also a great idea for a project! However, it seems to contradict what you first asked  - or maybe I just don't understand. Do you have a firm idea or are you looking for suggestions?

Comment: Yeah I do. No it didn't contradict what I said before. I said I would like to learn how to generate sound in C++. My project, would allow me to create timbres. Timbre is that quality which allows you do distinguishing the voice of an instrument from the voice of another instrument. What I don't get, is why you have such a hard time getting it. Picture goes in, sound comes out, -AND- vice-versa because it is sound editing and storage and production format. (More on its way)

Comment: (Continued from last) A long rectangular bmp where ever pixel along X is a single 'moment' and all pixels along Y are the volumes of the tones within the 'range'. Big X= long, Big Y= lots of tones. 3 y, n x, would give you a: rough gradation between the fringes of your selected range with a single tone in-between of a pitch equivalent to the average of your selected maximums/minimums, and the "song" would be of 'n' length. One of my pet peaves is being told I'm contradicting myself, when I personally feel that I have not (sorry)(people sometimes feel that way because I get intricate I think)

Comment: Not trying to be rude, I been up all night so my social skills took a dip. I am not trying to be hostile to you, but I'd like you to explicitly state the apparent contradiction, since: I am human too

Comment: Don't worry, I don't think you are rude. I am multi-tasking while replying to you, so maybe I am missing the point. I originally thought it was sounds in -> picture out; now I see from your comment that it is picture in -> sound out, so it was ***I*** who made a mistake. Sorry. Now I see where bitmaps come into it (bangs head on desk).  So, you want to "play" a picture, pixel by pixel? Then if you can read the picture in code, fine; if not, ask for a library. Also ask for a library for generating sounds. Suddenly it seems simple, and my comment/answer looks like it out to be deleted. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would work vice-versa too, but, if you make something in ms paint, along with the required metadata, and stick it in: you can get sound out, or if you take a wav or flac or raw (not sure which is simplest) file in you'd get a picture out. Ideally it'd also act like somewhat of an editor environmental so that you could tweak and review things real time you know?

Comment: Additionally the lowest frequency in your range, determines the minimum time-unit allowed within your metadata (so some error checking will be required), as: the minimum unit of time duration must be atleast: equal to or larger than: the frequency of your lowest wavelengths (obviously once you think about it that's obvious) (you can't fit a big wave in a small pool‍♂️)